# WordPress blocking/preventing viewing of .cgi file in subdirectory

Tags: redirect, htaccess, 404-error

I have a .cgi file, `/data/displayQuery.cgi`, that WordPress is showing a generic *"Page not found!"* error page for. I have my `.htaccess` file configured to not rewrite any file in the `/data` subdirectory. I've included my `.htaccess` code below (the `.htaccess` file is in the root directory of my WordPress installation):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(data|data/.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I created two test files, with a `.php` and `.html` file extension, that I can access just fine with no "Page not found!" error, and the contents of the file can be seen just fine with the above `.htaccess` file.

I tried using an `iframe` to display the CGI file in either a PHP or HTML file, but the `iframe` becomes the "Page not found!" error.

Entering the URL for a file in the `/data` directory that does not exist brings up a 404 error page from my hosting provider, NOT from WordPress. WordPress is blocking my `.cgi` file for some reason; how can I use `.htaccess` to unblock this file, or possibly use a WordPress function to add a exception for this file?

Comment: What is the full path to the file? And how are you creating the links to it?

Comment: /public_html/data/displayQuery.cgi is the full path (WP is installed in the root directory), I intend to link to the file from WordPress pages if that's what you mean.

Comment: No, what I asked was ***how*** not "what". How are you creating the links? Though it doesn't actually matter since you are getting the "404 error page from my hosting provider". This isn't WordPress. The server is getting involved before WordPress comes into play. You need to talk to the host.

Comment: I was able to solve the issue with a friend, and it was a server issue. Thank you for your help!